# I cannot serialize a sub class that is cast to its base class over GWT

Tags: gwt, serialization

I am having trouble serializing an object over GWT that contains a sub class that is cast to its base class. My class hierarchy is as follows:

```
public class BaseManagedObject implements IsSerializable
{
    public Shortcut getShortcut()
    {
        return new Shortcut();
    }
}

public class User extends BaseManagedObject implements IsSerializable
{
    public Shortcut getShortcut()
    {
        return new DomainMemberShortcut();
    }
}

public class Shortcut implements IsSerializeable {}

public class DomainMemberShortcut extends Shortcut implements IsSerializable {}
```

When I serialize a User object, I get "The response could not be deserialized". If I change User to return a Shortcut in getShortcut(), there is no problem. I added code that references the DomainMemberShortcut, just to verify that I can build with it, and that works fine.

Any suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: Oops - I left out the default constructor in the subclass. GWT needs a no-arg constructor, which I had already added to Shortcut, the base class.

Comment: If you found the solution, you should write the answer and accept it. Really.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - I was missing the default no-arg constructor in the DomainMember subclass.